# Why am I getting this Ruby on Rails Error?: #index is missing a template for request formats: text/html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a beginner to Ruby on Rails and just web app development in general. I am having a lot of trouble trying to simply display another page. Here are my codes.

Routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#home'

  get '/recent', controller: 'recent', action: 'index'
end
```

Controller File:

```
class RecentController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end
end
```

and the "recent" html.erb file (Its directory is app>views>recent>recent.html.erb):

```
<h2>Recent Recipes!</h2>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I really tried to understand what is wrong, but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: rename `recent.html.erb` to`index.html.erb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you create an action, you must have a view (erb) with the same name, so, in this case you can modify the name of recent.html.erb to index.html.erb

Also you can modify the action in your routes from index to recent, and do the same change in the RecentController.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! It makes more sense now. I am slowly getting a hang of this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

By default Rails expects a view template in the folder with same name as the controller named after the controller's action. If you rename `recent.html.erb` to `index.html.erb` it should be ok